# Comparing values from two tables in a nested where clause.

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

This is a rather specific question. I'm working to create row restrictions in Business Objects and the customer wants records to fall within a certain range from another table. The problem is, you can only select one table. A work around I found was that I can select other tables in the WHERE clause.

For Example:

```
a.RE_UID = b.RE_UID
```

I have to use:

```
a.RE_UID IN 
      (select A.RE_UID
       from 
        TABLE1 A 
        join 
        TABLE2 B
        ON 
        A.RE_UID = B.RE_UID
      )
```

Where I'm stumped is that I need compare off another table with a BETWEEN. Something like:

```
A.CL_FROM_SVC_DTE BETWEEN B.EFF_DTE AND B.END_DTE
```

If I just try like I did above I get errors that it expected another character after WHERE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  TABLE2 
WHERE IN 
(select A.CL_FROM_SVC_DTE 
FROM TABLE1 A 
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.RE_UID = B.RE_UID
) 
BETWEEN B.EFF_DTE AND B.END_DTE
```

Comment: Why can't you perform joins normally?

Comment: Provide table definition with some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting everything from Table2 with the condition on Table1, what you could do is this:

```
SELECT T2.* FROM TABLE2 T2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T2.RE_UID = T1.RE_UID
WHERE T1.CL_FROM_SVC_DTE BETWEEN T2.EFF_DTE AND T2.END_DTE
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood neither the problem nor the restriction to select from one table alone, so this is an educated guess at best:

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM 
TABLE2 B
WHERE b.RE_UID IN (
    select a.RE_UID
    FROM TABLE1 A 
    WHERE A.CL_FROM_SVC_DTE BETWEEN B.EFF_DTE 
                                AND B.END_DTE A.RE_UID
);
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't blame you. Basically, I'm working on creating Restrictions to a Universe in Business Objects. Customer wants certain users to have records with specific dates. In Business Objects when creating Row-Level Restrictions you can only select one table at a time without in joins. Basically, the restrictions work only as WHERE clauses (I think, anyways). So basically when you create a restriction on a table you choose the table and you choose the WHERE clause. If I choose Table1 it will and put in the WHERE clause BOBJ automatically creates Select * from WHERE (whatever I enter)